# BATCH file error - Exception in thread "main" but compiles and runs fine without batch file

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file to automate the compiling and execution of java programs. Here is my batch script:

```
@echo off
cd X:\
echo Compile/Execute Java
echo Author: Phil Eaton
echo Created: 09-28-2012
set /P file=File name: %=%
set java = %file%.java
javac %java%
java %file%
set /P quit=
```

However it is returning "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld" where HelloWorld is the user input. However when I run javac HelloWorld.java in the command prompt, it compiles fine, and when I run java HelloWorld it also runs fine. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: is the HelloWorld file located in x:\? otherwise, you might need to pass a classpath or sourcepath option ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#options))

Comment: What are you doing with the `%=%` business?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` doesn't allow spaces around `=`:

```
set java=%file%.java
```

Comment: +1, But technically, SET does allow spaces. The space before `=` will become part of the variable name, and the space after `=` will become part of the value.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

```
@rem Compile and run Java program
@if "%1"=="" goto USAGE

javac %1%.java
java %1%
@goto THE_END

:USAGE
@echo EXAMPLE USAGE: doit HelloJava
@goto THE_END

:THE_END
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the spaces:

```
set java=%file%.java
```

When the spaces are present, the `java` variable will be empty. Alternatively you can use:

```
set java = "%file%.java"
```